# How to re-add date and time into OneNote page?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote

You have an option to delete the date and time on a OneNote page under the title on the native application (not the UWP that comes free with Windows 10)

[image]

My question now is, how do I re-add it to the page? For example I decide at a later time that I wanted to have a date and time on the page after all?

Comment: [Relevant microsoft support arcitle](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-the-current-date-and-time-on-a-page-786d1d74-fb43-43c2-8ccd-5cf7cdab8141)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Relevant microsoft support arcitle:](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-the-current-date-and-time-on-a-page-786d1d74-fb43-43c2-8ccd-5cf7cdab8141)

```
In your notes, place the cursor where you want to insert the current date and time.

Do one of the following:

    Click Insert, and then click either Date, Time, or Date & Time.
```

[image]

```
    To insert the current date and time, press Alt+Shift+F.

    To insert only the date, press Alt+Shift+D.

    To insert only the time, press Alt+Shift+T.
```

Comment: That only inserts the date and time into the page's body, not directly under the title